# TailwindCSS arbitrary values don't work in default redwood and tailwind install

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, redwoodjs

I have this piece of code, everything in tailwind works in this code except for arbitrary values for some reason does any one have any clue why?

```
    return (
        <ul>
            {names.map((name: string, index: number) => {
                let shiftVal: number = 96;
                let classNameLink: string = `text-red-500 bg-red-500 hover:text-white
                flex justify-around box-border w-96 
                relative left-[${index * shiftVal}px] py-4 mb-[${shiftVal * ((index / (index + 5e-324)) + 1)}px]
                transition-all
                `
                return (
                    <a href = {links[index]} key={index} className={classNameLink} >{name}</a>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

[image]

I used `yarn rw setup ui tailwind` to install tailwind CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tailwind does not support dynamic classes, such as the ones you are trying to create. The full utility class name must be available at build time in your code for Tailwind to find it and generate the proper CSS classes.

One solution is to add your dynamic styles in the `styles` attribute instead of using Tailwind CSS utility classes. For example:

```
{
  names.map((name: string, index: number) => {
    let shiftVal: number = 96;
    return (
      <a
        href={links[index]}
        key={index}
        className='text-red-500 bg-red-500 hover:text-white flex justify-around box-border w-96 relative py-4 transition-all'
        style={{
          left: `${index * shiftVal}px`,
          marginBottom: `${shiftVal * (index / (index + 5e-324) + 1)}px`
        }}
      >
        {name}
      </a>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the method works perfectly, but this code has an error in it.

Comment: I guess I should've added, "...untested". What was the issue?

Answer (score -2):

TailwindCSS doesn't allow you to generate classes dynamically. So when you use the following to generate the class…

```
left-[${index * shiftVal}px] py-4 mb-[${shiftVal * ((index / (index + 5e-324)) + 1)}px]
```

…TailwindCSS will not pick that up as a valid TailwindCSS class and therefore will not produce the necessary CSS.

Instead, you must include the full name of the class in your source code. You can return the full value like this

```
function  myFunc(index,shiftVal) {
return `left-[${index * shiftVal}px] py-4 mb-[${shiftVal * ((index / (index + 5e-324)) + 1)}px]`
}
```

where `index & shiftVal` is the value you are passing here.

And use it like this

```
<ul>
            {names.map((name: string, index: number) => {
                let shiftVal: number = 96;
                let classNameLink: string = `text-red-500 bg-red-500 hover:text-white
                flex justify-around box-border w-96 
                relative ${myFunc}
                transition-all
                `
                return (
                    <a href = {links[index]} key={index} className={classNameLink} >{name}</a>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
```

By doing it this way, the entire string for every class is in your source code, so TailwindCSS will know to generate the applicable CSS.

Read more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

### Edit

Try this function

```
function  myFunc(index,shiftVal) {
return "left-[", index * shiftVal,"px] py-4 mb-[",shiftVal * ((index / (index + 5e-324)) + 1),"px]"
}
```

### EDIT -2

This should work

```
  function  myFunc(index,shiftVal) {
return `left-['${index * shiftVal}px'] py-4 mb-['${shiftVal * ((index / (index + 5e-324)) + 1)}px']`
}
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't fix the problem the second red div only shifts to all other divs, the code in the function still works but specifically classes with attribute values do not work.
(if you wonder why did the second div move, my guess is that `left-[${index * shiftVal}px]` was for some reason working. maybe it was just not interpreted as attribute value.)

Comment: I had edited my answer please check now

Comment: Your new version gives an error `Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.ts(2695)
`
So I changed it into this and it still doesn't work.
`"left-[" + index * shiftVal + "px] py-4 mb-[" + shiftVal * ((index / (index + 5e-324)) + 1) +"px]"`

Comment: Means you understand that you will need to return this as a `complete string` with variables incorporated in it, then try to do that.

Comment: I had made changes in my answer under heading `edit-2`. Please check now

Comment: It doesn't work, I think it has to do with how `yarn rw setup ui tailwind` sets tailwind up and not with the fact that tailwind can't identify classes because it can, as how you can see it did with the second div on the screenshot. Not sure why it doesn't move the other divs trought.

Comment: Okay, please do upvote if my answer finds helpful for you