# Template literal not working correctly with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, tailwind-css, template-literals

I am passing in a Hex Colour into a prop and attempting to set the background of an element with it. Here is my code:

```
 let cardColourRGB: string;
 if (cardColour) {
   cardColourRGB = "[" + cardColour + "]";
   console.log(cardColourRGB);
 } else {
   cardColourRGB = "white/50"
 }
```

In the `return` function:

```
 <div className={`bg-${cardColourRGB}`}></div>
```

Passing in some colours work, but others don't. For example, passing in #AAA32E as the prop does not set the colour, but setting the colour directly works:

```
<div className={`bg-[#AAA32E]`}></div>
```

Why could this be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically craft Tailwind classes with Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71779219/programmatically-craft-tailwind-classes-with-vue)

Comment: If the color being passed is an arbitrary value, you can best handle this issue by using a `style` attribute instead of trying to create a dynamic Tailwind class. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825061/tailwindcss-arbitrary-values-dont-work-in-default-redwood-and-tailwind-install/72830825#72830825

Answer (score 12):

According to the official documentation of the `tailwind.css` it is not preferred to have such `classNames`

As document says:

- The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
- If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:

*Don't construct class names dynamically*

```
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
```

*Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full*

```
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
```

**So , for your case, use the following code:**

```
<div class="{{ cardColour ? 'bg-[#AAA32E]' : 'bg-white-50' }}"></div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

TailwindCSS doesn't allow you to generate classes dynamically. So when you use the following to generate the class…

```
`bg-${cardColourRGB}`
```

…TailwindCSS will not pick that up as a valid TailwindCSS class and therefore will not produce the necessary CSS.

Instead, you must include the full name of the class in your source code. You can  return the full value like this

```
let cardColourRGB: string;
 if (cardColour) {
   cardColourRGB = "bg-[" + cardColour + "]";
   console.log(cardColourRGB);
 } else {
   cardColourRGB = "bg-white/50"
 }
```

where `cardColourRGB` is your  value you are passing .

By doing it this way, the entire string for every class is in your source code, so TailwindCSS will know to generate the applicable CSS.

Read more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

Answer (score 2):

the best solution is to use the style property/attribute on the element instead

```
<div className={`w-4 h-1 relative etc...`} style={{backgroundColor: cardColourRGB}}></div>
```